# jupyter: команда не найдена

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook

Вчера работал, а сегодня стал недоступен jupyter. 2й раз за год. В 1й раз починил, добавить путь экспорта в .bashrc.
Сейчас там, среди прочего, есть строки:

```
export PYTHONPATH="~/anaconda3/bin" 
export PATH=$PATH:~/anaconda3/bin 
export LIBRARY_PATH="/home/boris/anaconda3/lib"
export 
PATH="/home/boris/anaconda3/bin/python:$PATH" 
export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin
export export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

Обновления на ubuntu поставил, обновить conda не смог, то же самое - нет такой команды.

Что делать?

Comment: что показывает `locate conda | grep bin` ?

Comment: возвращает сотни путей в разных папках /home/boris/anaconda3

Comment: если `conda` не запускается вообще, то у вас проблемы с переменной окружения `PATH`. `PATH` должен содержать директорию,в которой находится бинарник `conda`

Comment: Это понятно. Но все пути прописаны (см. топик) и лежат в .bashrc. Значит, anaconda и jupyter перестали запускаться из путей, указанных в этом файле. Поэтому вопросы следующие: (1) из какого файла они теперь берут пути?  (2) Почему это произошло, почему соскочила  настройка на  .bashrc?

Comment: А что у вас в системе поменялось перед тем как возникла проблема? `.bashrc` бывает локальным и глобальным. Кроме `.bashrc` у вас могут запускаться другие скрипты изменяющие окружение.  Чтобы ответить на ваш первый похоже надо иметь доступ к данной машине. 2. что значит соскочила настройка? Как выглядел `.bashrc` когда все работало?

Comment: В том и дело что ничего не менялось, я даже обычных обновлений не ставил уже неделю. К компу кроме меня доступа ни у кого нет, т.е. на машине профиль единственный. Год назад, как вспоминаю, было также. Файлик .bashrc лежит в ~ и выглядит обычно, в конце файла почти 2 десятка путей для export, некоторые я привёл в топике. Подскажите, в какие файлы мне дописать эти пути? Команда 'echo $path' ничего не выдаёт, пустая строка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена сносом и переустановкой анаконды. 
Откуда проблема взялась остаётся загадкой, единственное предположение - прилетело какое-то кривое обновление. 
Второй неприятный момент - в .bashrc все пути были прописаны корректно, все файлы и папки были ок, почему не лечилось - непонятно.

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте переименовать `.bashrc` в `.bashrc.SAV` и создать новый `.bashrc` со следующим содержимым:

```
export PYTHONPATH="$HOME/anaconda3/bin" 
export PATH=$HOME/anaconda3/bin:$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/anaconda3/lib
```

чтобы посмотреть текущее настройки путей:

```
echo $PATH
```

чтобы посмотреть все переменные окружения:

```
env
```

Comment: Переименовал bashrc в .bashrc.SAV, создал новый, не помогает(